# Extra zeros appear at the end of existing items when appending new lists to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to solve Pascal triangle prblem on leetcode: "Return a given number of Pascal triangle rows". I've defined a function `getNextRow(row)` that calculates the next rows given the current one and then calling it a certain number of times and appending these rows to my resulting list. For some reason extra zero appears at the end of the previous row each time I'm adding a new row.

E.g.
Input: `5 #5 rows needed`

Output: `[[1,0],[1,1,0],[1,2,1,0],[1,3,3,1,0],[1,4,6,4,1]]`

Expected output: `[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]`

```
def getNextRow(row):
    res = [1]
    if len(row) == 0:
        return res
    row.append(0)
    for i in range(len(row) - 1):
        res.append(row[i] + row[i+1])
    return res


def generate(numRows):
    pascal = [] #Empty resulting triangle
    currentRow = []
    num = 0 #Counter
    while num < numRows:
        currentRow = getNextRow(currentRow)
        pascal.append(currentRow)
        num += 1
    return pascal
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(generate(5))
```

Comment: `row.append(0)` is adding `0` to the row.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because you are reusing the variable `currentRow` on each iteration. In the fourth line of the `getNextRow` function, you are appending `0` to the row passed in to the variable. This is directly referencing the `currentRow` variable in memory and therefore making changes before the `currentRow` is added to the `pascal` list. To fix this, you can either copy the `currentRow` before you add it to the `pascal` list e.g:

```py
pascal.append(currentRow.copy())
```

or copy the `row` variable within `getNextRow` like so:

```py
def getNextRow(row):
    row = row.copy()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You append zero to *row* in *getNextRow()*. That entry in the list never gets modified so you'll always see a redundant trailing zero.

Your code is also rather cumbersome. Here's a more concise implementation:-

```
def pascal(n):
    r = [[1]]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        p = r[-1]
        r.append([1] + [p[j-1] + p[j] for j in range(1, i-1)] + [1])
    return r

print(pascal(6))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]]
```